# How to capture the image simultaniously while scanning QR code in Android?

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to **capture the image of QR code which comes under rectangular brackets while scanning**. I know that QR code image can be easily generated and displayed but my requirement is to display the exact same image of QR code which is scanned.

I have tried below code:

```
scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });

.....

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null){
            Bitmap btm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            btm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            image.setImageBitmap(btm);
            if(result.getContents() == null){

                android.widget.Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                android.widget.Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

But I am getting null bitmap.

Comment: please show us the code you've tried and why it's not working

Comment: Hi Keith M, I have added the code which I tried.

Comment: looks like you need to set "setBarcodeImageEnabled" to true. See https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/143

Comment: Thanks Keith M, it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: your welcome! I made an answer from my comment, if you could accept it them that would be great

Answer (score 1):

Use Below code inside **onActivityResult** for getting the image

```
String path = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_IMAGE_PATH");
File file = new File(path);
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set "setBarcodeImageEnabled" to true so the Barcode scanner captures to varicose images. Then when getting the Barcode results, you can get the images.

```
@override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    result.getBitmap()
    result.getBitmapWithResultPoints(Color.YELLOW)
}
```

source: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/143

Comment: Hi, Both method showing the error that 'Cannot resolve method'.I have added below dependency in build.grdle.Please help.....    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.3@aar'